# activity_main.xml: String index out of range: 0 in Android Code

Tags: android, eclipse, apk, indexof

That's my activity_main.xml, when I try see my Graphical it's returned any errors:

Exception raised during rendering: String index out of range: 0
Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log
The following classes could not be found:
- EditText (Change to android.widget.EditText, Fix Build Path, Edit XML)

I guess have something with error "activity_main.xml: String index out of range: 0" any like that menssage in my View.

Have anybody can I help me?

Down is my activity:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lblPeso"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="@string/peso_" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/lblPeso"
    android:ems="10" android:inputType="none">

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lblAltura"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
    android:text="@string/altura_" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/lblAltura"
    android:layout_below="@+id/lblAltura"
    android:ems="10" android:inputType="none"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonCalcular"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText2"
    android:text="@string/calcular_" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/buttonCalcular"
    android:ems="10" android:inputType="none"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:ems="10" android:inputType=""/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/buttonCalcular"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText3"
    android:text="@string/imc_" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText4"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText3"
    android:text="@string/pesoIdeal_" />
```

(ANDROID)

Comment: can we have java code and logcat ?

Comment: can you post your exception stack trace?

Comment: can you try to remove <requestFocus /> ?

Comment: Please post your java code.

Comment: See this: http://www.coderanch.com/t/410825/java/java/String-index-range-exception

Comment: I thought the error, It was here:

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:ems="10" android:inputType=""/> --------------<<<<

I seted the none into inputType and back to normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your xml is wrong, please correct all your left_below etc. declarations inside the xml. For example, You wrote:

```
        <EditText
     android:id="@+id/editText1"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:layout_below="@+id/lblPeso"
     android:ems="10" android:inputType="none">
```

but it has to be:

```
     <EditText
     android:id="@+id/editText1"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:layout_below="@id/lblPeso" <---- Here is the issue
     android:ems="10" android:inputType="none">
```

correct this in the complete layout everywhere you have done this. You wrote layout_below="@+id/...."  but it hast to be layout_below="@id/..."

Comment: May be you are right. I dont know the difference between `@+id/lblPeso` and `@id/lblPeso`. But i don't think this creates any problem as i have been using `@+id/lblPeso` since i started learning android. I never came across any kind of issues.

Comment: You need @+id to give an id to a view, and You need @id to reference to another view, thats the difference. The error You get, could be thrown if something is wrong inside your xml declaration of your view. Try it......

Comment: Okay sir. I got you. I'll definitely try it. Thanks for clearing my doubt. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I tryed it, but my application run, but I can't manipulate my View, on Ecplise is showed a gray screen on View place.

Comment: the preview in eclipse is not like a real device. It got some issues when showing preview. Please test it on emulator or better on a real device.What You want to do with Your view, how do Yu want to manipulate?

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem and I removed the autofillhints (in the xml file) and it worked.

```
android:autofillHints=""
```

Answer (score 1):

Having just run into the same issue, the problem is with the empty inputType (android:inputType="") in OP's editText4.

Answer (score 0):

put none in "" will be "none" in edit text4

`<EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:ems="10" android:inputType="none"/>`

Answer (score 0):

I have ever met this exception when I was working with a layout XML file in Android Studio. As this snapshot:
[Exception raised during rendering: String index out of range: 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7U0i.png)

And I delete one of my code:

```
android:layout_gravity=""
```

After that the exception is gone.

---

So as for you, replace your code:

```
android:inputType=""
```

with

```
android:inputType="none"
```